# Thumbnail in Text Files with WebView

Tags: android, webview, text-files, thumbnails, google-docs

I have a files's list in my Android app and I want put them a preview image, an icon (thumbnail).

I have got this purpose for image and video files, but not for text files.
In this last case, I know there is a Google Docs function that it creates an image from a text file that it can be used like thumbnail:

**http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=MY_LINK&a=bi&pagenumber=1&w=300**

Here, you can put the text file url, the number page and the width for thumbnail.
This method works well, but I don't know like obtaining the image created with this url, for saving in a Bitmap and put it in the icon ImageView.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: You can use  HttpClient or UrlConnection to download the image. What is exactly your problem?

Comment: My problem is that I want use the image generated in this url but I dont want download it. Is there any form to obtain the image from webview without download it? Thanks

Comment: If you want to use that image you have to download it ofcourse. `to obtain the image from webview`. ?? It's time you explain what a webview has to do with this all. Explain better what you have and want to do please.